# Displaying NorthArrow on ArcObjects axSceneControl?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst, arcgis-engine, north-arrow

I have standalone application (ArcObjects C# 10.3) uses axSceneControl.
How to display on the scene NorthArrow or Directional Arrow or something like that?
I found an example for NorthArrow http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0049/00490000004w000000.htm but for IPageLayot.

Comment: Unless you build you own mock north arrow from features (very possible but very static) there isn't a way to add a dynamic 3D north arrow to a scene. iPageLayout is the ArcMap 2D layous which is completaly different from ArcScene so that example will not work. If you want to know how to add a static north arrow to a ArcScene, I could provide some instructions.

Comment: Yes please describe your method.

Comment: @JakubSisakGeoGraphics could you provide some instructions.